# ProductInsert() does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
protected void Btn_CheckOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = 0;

    Payment user = new Payment(txt_CardNumber.Text, txt_CardHolderName.Text, txt_ExpirationDate.Text, txt_Cvv.Text);
    result = ProductInsert();
   /* Session["CardNumber"] = txt_CardNumber.Text;
    Session["CardHolderName"] = txt_CardHolderName.Text;
    Session["ExpirationDate"] = txt_ExpirationDate.Text;
    Session["Cvv"] = txt_Cvv.Text;*/

    Response.Redirect("Payment Sucessful.aspx");
}

public int ProductInsert()
{
    int result = 0;
    string queryStr = "INSERT INTO CustomerDetails(CardNumber, CardHolderName, ExpirationDate, Cvv)"
                      + "values (@CardNumber,@CardHolderName, @ExpirationDate, @Cvv)";
    try
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardNumber", this.CardNumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardHolderName", this.CardHolderName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpirationDate", this.ExpirationDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cvv", this.Cvv);
        conn.Open();
        result += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Returns no. of rows affected. Must be > 0
        conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to store credit card informations into database. I have created a `productInsert()` method and now I am trying to insert whatever values into the database.

This code is giving the error:

> ProductInsert() does not exist in current context

Comment: Be VERY careful about storing credit card information. PCI DSS compliance issues will come up.

Comment: p.s If you're new to programming I'd go as far as saying you shouldn't be storing credit card information at all. You can hold it in memory up until the point you charge the card (or better still get a token for the card and use that).

Comment: i am actually doing it for a school project i was told to encrypt the creedit card sand store it inside

Comment: Ok fair enough but even with encryption, storing the information isn't advised unless your the likes of Amazon etc who have a PCI compliance rating meaning they can do what they like.